# проблема с broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, kotlin, broadcast-receiver

Хочу "словить" системное событие в `android`, а именно `connect/disconnect` зарядного устройства. Создал `receiver` но он не срабатывает. С офиц. сайта узнал что с 28 версии api введено ограничение на использование ресиверов и разделение на явные/неявные и привязку последних к контексту приложения. Но пробовал даже на версиях ниже 8 `android`, а результата нет. Как такое событие поймать? Использовать `JobScheduler` не вариант.

**manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />

<receiver
        android:name=".data.ChargeReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**ChargeReceiver.kt**

```
class ChargeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    companion object {
        const val TAG = "ChargeReceiver"
    }
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "receiver called...")
    }
}
```

Comment: я хоть и не уверен, да и в Kotlin не очень, но уверены ли вы что у вас система не прибивает его, чтобы освободить ресурсы. Также интересует вопрос, а где методы на подобии onStart, onResume, onDestroy (Java), где можно уже самим receiver работать, подписываться и т.д. Или в котлине за это все отвечает onReceive?

Comment: По-моему Вы не те `action` применили. Зарядка - это не usb-устройство, хотя и использует тот же порт. Пробуйте [`ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)

Comment: @woesss, пробовал, забыл об этом написать

Comment: @danilshik, вы говорите об динамических приемниках, я пытаюсь созадать автономный которому привязка к fragment/activity не нужна, только обьявление в манифесте.

Comment: @UjinUkr кажется я понял, вы хотите, чтобы broadcastrecevier работал даже при закрытом приложении (через manifest), а динамический работает, только когда работает приложение, так?

Comment: @danilshik, да.

Comment: Как бы в документации приведён такой же код и ни слова о том, что так делать нельзя: [MonitorChargeState](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring#MonitorChargeState). Но ресиверы не работают, если приложение было убито и/или не запущено юзером. А так же существуют "медвежьи услуги" от производителей аппаратов в виде программы-блокировщика всех фоновых телодвижений и необходимости ручками заносить им в белый список нужные приложения.

Comment: @woesss, пример с документации работает только с версиями меньше 8. Выходит теперь нужно обязательно делать явную привязку к UI?

Comment: Да, разбросали инфу... Вот [тут список](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) того, что можно регистрировать в манифесте и `ACTION_POWER_` там нет. Значит только через контекст либо таки делать `Job`